# Can gcc compile x86 assembly or just link it?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

gcc can produce assembly but how do I compile pure assembly with gcc or other compiler? I know x86 assembly is difficult and another instruction set than the MIPS and Nios I was looking at but now I want to try to compile direct x86 asm. There are instruction for how to do it but there's a C file included and I don't need a C file for my first most basic compile.

```
gcc -o test_asm asm_functions.S test_asm.c
```

There's the step creating `.o` files

```
gcc -c asm_functions.S
gcc -c test_asm.c
gcc -o test_asm asm_functions.o test_asm.o
```

But I don't see the step where I can directly compile x86 asm with gcc. There's another program named GNU as (GNU Assembler), can it be used to translate x86 assembly to machine code?

### Test

Code (32.s)

```
.globl  _start

.text
_start:
        movl    $len, %edx
        movl    $msg, %ecx
        movl    $1, %ebx
        movl    $4, %eax
        int     $0x80

        movl    $0, %ebx
        movl    $1, %eax
        int     $0x80
.data
msg:
        .ascii  "Hello, world!\n"
        len =   . - msg
```

Steps

```
$ gcc -c 32.s 
$ ls 32*
32.o  32.s
$ gcc -o 32 32.o 
32.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

So it seems it may have mixed 32 and 64 bits, must I tell the complier whether the assembly is 32 or 64 bit instructions?

### Update

This test worked with gcc.

```
$ cat hello.s
.data
.globl hello
hello:
.string "Hi World\n"

.text
.global main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp,       %rbp
    movq    $hello,     %rdi
    call    puts
    movq    $0,         %rax
    leave
    ret
$ gcc hello.s -o hello
$ ./hello 
Hi World
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `as(1)` does.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) on how to assemble and link using gcc, for programs that define `_start` or `main`, with/without libc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're already doing it.

```
gcc -c asm_functions.S
```

That step produces an object file, `asm_functions.o`.  The object file is "linkable" (as opposed to "loadable") file that contains the machine code, with some extra instructions for how the linker should modify the code when linking.  The `gcc` program itself is just a driver, it runs `as` behind the scenes for you to produce `asm_functions.o`.  So you do have the option of running `as` directly, but often it's easier to run the `gcc` frontend.

Comment: But when I try to link just an object file created from pure assembly I get an error message I can't understand (`In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'` Thank you for the answer.

Comment: That's a linking problem, not a compiling problem!  If you use `gcc` to link, you get the C runtime by default, and your entry point should be `main`.

Comment: Thanks. It works (`gcc hello.s -o hello`) to compile and run to x86 assembly now. I updated the question with the code and cmd I use. I didn't try whether this code is spec to linux, it may be other assembly for other operating systems and the `as` program might also compile it but in this case I could use `gcc` with a simple hello world program to compile and run x86 assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Although the update works, the original code could have been compiled by simply using `gcc -nostdlib`.  For example,

```
gcc -nostdlib 32.s -o 32
```

Comment: Unlikely that passing your name as a parameter would have much effect. And what's that random 32? Using line breaks and code formatting would make your answer much more readable.

Comment: Some code will also benefit from (or require) `-no-pie` on modern distros.  no-pie used to be the default, but isn't anymore in most modern GNU/Linux distro GCC configs.  Especially for 64-bit code using absolute addresses.  With `gcc -m32 -nostdlib foo.S`, it may still work to build a PIE, but if you do link libc then you need puts@plt or manual -fno-plt asm;see [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131094)